# How to trim the header in a fasta sequence to the species name and keeping the main text of the sequence using sed command?

Tags: sed, header, fasta

The fasta file name: STD_PRO_1.fasta

I have multiple headers in that fasta file as such:

**>ENA|AB000176|AB000176.1 Escherichia coli DNA for mannosyl transferase, phosphoribosyl-ATP pyrophosphohydrolase:phosphoribosyl-AMP cyclohydrolase, partial cds.**
GACCATATGATTGACGCCTATGTCAATCTCTACACTACATTGCTGGAAAGCAAATCCTGA
GAGATGCTACCCCCGCCGTTGCTGCGGGGGCCAACGCGTTAATGCCGATTCTTCAGATTA
TCAATCACTTCTCCGAGATCCAGCCCTTGATCCTGCAACAACACCAGCAGGTGATACATC
AAATCAGATGCCTCGTTGGTCAGTTCAAAGCGGTCATGTACTGTCGCTGCCAGTGCGGTT

**>ENA|AB000178|AB000178.1 Escherichia coli DNA for mannosyl transferase, phosphoribosyl-ATP pyrophosphohydrolase:phosphoribosyl-AMP cyclohydrolase, partial cds.**
GACCATATGATTGACGCCTATGTCAATCTCTACACTACATTGCTGGAAAGCAAATCCTGA
GAGATGCTACCCCCGCCGTTGCTGCGGGGGCCAATGCGTTAATGCCGATTCTTCAGATTA
TCAATCACTTCTCCGAGATCCAGCCCCTGATCCTGTAACAGCACCAGCAGGTGATACATC
AAATCAGATGCCTCGTTGGTCAGCTCAAAGCGGTCATGTACCGTTGGTGCCAGTGCGGTT

To keep only the species name in the header as follows:

**>Escherichia coli**
GACCATATGATTGACGCCTATGTCAATCTCTACACTACATTGCTGGAAAGCAAATCCTGA
GAGATGCTACCCCCGCCGTTGCTGCGGGGGCCAACGCGTTAATGCCGATTCTTCAGATTA
TCAATCACTTCTCCGAGATCCAGCCCTTGATCCTGCAACAACACCAGCAGGTGATACATC
AAATCAGATGCCTCGTTGGTCAGTTCAAAGCGGTCATGTACTGTCGCTGCCAGTGCGGTT

**>Escherichia coli**
GACCATATGATTGACGCCTATGTCAATCTCTACACTACATTGCTGGAAAGCAAATCCTGA
GAGATGCTACCCCCGCCGTTGCTGCGGGGGCCAATGCGTTAATGCCGATTCTTCAGATTA
TCAATCACTTCTCCGAGATCCAGCCCCTGATCCTGTAACAGCACCAGCAGGTGATACATC
AAATCAGATGCCTCGTTGGTCAGCTCAAAGCGGTCATGTACCGTTGGTGCCAGTGCGGTT

Comment: How do you know what the species name is e.g. in `Escherichia coli DNA for mannosyl` - is `DNA` always present?  So whatever comes before `DNA`?

Comment: I have checked the headers for each sequence, and yes, the species name always comes before DNA or gene

Comment: `sed '/^>/{ s/[^ ]* />/; s/ DNA.*//; s/ gene.*//; }'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this command on a test fasta file, but it removed all the headers and their sequences which has DNA or genes

Comment: It works, thanks very much @KarlT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before:

```
$ sed -n l test.fasta
>ENA|AB000176|AB000176.1 Escherichia coli DNA for mannosyl transferase$
GACCATATGATTGACGCCTATGTCAATCTCTACACTACATTGCTGGAAAGCAAATCCTGA GAGATGCTA$
$
>ENA|AB000178|AB000178.1 Escherichia coli DNA for mannosyl transferase$
GACCATATGATTGACGCCTATGTCAATCTCTACACTACATTGCTGGAAAGCAAATCCTGA GAGATGCTA$
```

After:

```
$ sed '/^>/{ s/[^ ]* />/; s/ DNA.*//; s/ gene.*//; }' test.fasta
>Escherichia coli
GACCATATGATTGACGCCTATGTCAATCTCTACACTACATTGCTGGAAAGCAAATCCTGA GAGATGCTA

>Escherichia coli
GACCATATGATTGACGCCTATGTCAATCTCTACACTACATTGCTGGAAAGCAAATCCTGA GAGATGCTA
```

Comment: This done the job: 
sed '/^>/{ s/[^ ]* />/; s/ DNA.*//; s/ gene.*//; }' STD_PRO_1.fasta